# array_intersection parital matches in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
$array1 = array("dog","cat","butterfly")
$array2 = array("dogs","cat","bird","cows")
```

I need to get all partial matches from $array2 compared to $array1 like so:

```
array("dog","cat")
```

So I need to check if there are partial word matches in $array2 and output new array with $array1 keys and values.

`array_intersection` only outputs full matches

Thanks

Comment: What is partial match?

Comment: it means that if array2 has bulldog and array1 has dog then we can say that we found dog from array2 and we can add it to our output array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more way to get the same result

```
<?php

   $array1 = array("dog","cat","butterfly");
   $array2 = array("dogs","cat","bird","cows");

   // Array output will be displayed from this array
   $result_array = $array1;

   // Array values are compared with each values of above array
   $search_array = $array2;


   print_r( array_filter($result_array, function($e) use ($search_array) {
       return preg_grep("/$e/",$search_array);
   }));

?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => dog
    [1] => cat
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$array1 = array("dog","cat","butterfly");
$array2 = array("dogs","cat","bird","cows");

function partial_intersection($a,$b){
    $result = array();
    foreach($a as $v){
        foreach($b as $val){
            if( strstr($val,$v) || strstr($v,$val) ){ $result[] = $v; }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(partial_intersection($array1,$array2));
```

Comment: Why don't you simplify like this `if( strstr($val,$v) || strstr($v,$val) ){ $result[] = $v; }`